# Undefined symbol after library search - CLIPPER

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, clipperlib, clipper

I have tried to compile an application written in Clipper 5.2.
It is experiencing an error which I believe is the inclusion of libraries.
The moment that I linked, it displays the following error:

I'm using: **rtlink fi MyApp**

[image: Error compile - Clipper]
Stretch of code where I import libraries:

```
#include "INKEY.CH"
#include "GRUMP.CH"
#include "BOX.CH"
#include "GRUMPBRO.CH"
#include "BOXGET.CH"
REQUEST dbfcdx
function Weekextr()
enter code here
```

Someone with knowledge clipper could help me?

Comment: http://www.ousob.com/ng/cldriv/ng1d046.php

Comment: http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.clipper/clipper-5.2d-unresolved-externals-need-help/888730